# Java - Enhanced for loop for ArrayList with custom object

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Given this StudentList Class with ArrayList that takes Student Object with three fields: Roll number, Name and Marks, how to write enhanced For Loop instead of the regular For Loop method as written in the code below?

Student.java

```
public class Student {
private int rollNumber;
private String name;
private int marks;

public Student(int roll, String name, int marks){
    this.rollNumber=roll;
    this.name=name;
    this.marks=marks;
}

public int getRollNumber(){
    return this.rollNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getMarks() {
    return marks;
  }
}
```

Here is the SudentList Class with Main Method

StudentList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentList {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Student a = new Student(1, "Mark", 80);
Student b = new Student(2, "Kevin", 85);
Student c = new Student(3, "Richard", 90);

List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(a);
studentList.add(b);
studentList.add(c);

for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Roll number: " + 
  studentList.get(i).getRollNumber() +
                ", Name: " + studentList.get(i).getName() + ", Marks: " + 
  studentList.get(i).getMarks());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `for(Student student : studentList){// code}` means for **each** student in studentList...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of index, [**`foreach`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) gives you direct objects

```
for (Student st : studentList) {
       System.out.println("Roll number: " +  st.getRollNumber() + ", Name: " + st.getName() + ", Marks: " + st.getMarks());
    }
```

So whenever you see `list.get()` replace it with direct object reference and you are done.

Comment: so in this case Java takes care of the studentList.get(i) part?

Comment: @Econ_newbie It works in a different by using Iterator. Read more at the link given

Comment: @Econ_newbie For details, see the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).